# show a form in div by jquery after .html(' ');

Tags: html, ajax, forms, reload, logout

i want change div content when click button without reload page, and show again my form

i have this code

```
$('#reg_but').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'login.php',
     data: {
         user : document.reg.user.value,
     },
     success: function(data){
        if (data !=0){
            $('#my_div').html(data);
        }
     }
   })
});

function login_again(){
   $('#my_div').html(' ');
   $('#my_div').html( *here i want show reg form* ) 
   //  >>  Here i want load again my form (reg form) << This is my problem

}

<body>
    <div id="my_div">
      <form name='reg' id='reg'>
        <input name="user" class="user" id="user">
        <input type="submit" onClick="return reg_but();"
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="log_out" onClick="login_again()">Login Again & Log Out</div>
</body>
```

after the click submit show login.php result, then when click in login_again() i want show my form (reg form) in my_div.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear you want to do in login_again. Ajax is already trying to display new html from the web. Do you want to copy over the new html again?

Comment: Apart from that, this code isn't attaching the handler to submit button because id is missing. Try to return false for preventing the page from being posted instead of running Ajax. For starters I'd change your submit button to <input id="reg_but" type="submit" onclick="return false;"> In your html body, put the scripts at the end, otherwise the tags won't exist when jQuery tries to attach handlers. There may be other issues though.

Comment: Yes, i want to copy over the new html again. I want show again completly <form name='reg' id='reg'> ... </form> after click on Login Again

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery hide() and show(). [jQuery hide()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_hide.asp)

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by this code

index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#my_div').load('form.html');
});
function reg_but(){
       $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:'login.php',
         data: {
             user : $('#user').val(),
         },
         success: function(data){
            if (data !=0){
                $('#my_div').html(data);
            }
         }
       })
    };

    function login_again(){
       $('#my_div').html(' ');
       $('#my_div').load('form.html');

    }

    <body>
        <div id="my_div"></div>
        <div id="log_out" onClick="login_again()">Login Again & Log Out</div>
    </body>
```

form.html

```
<input name="user" class="user" id="user">
<input type="submit" onClick="return reg_but();">
```